# HTML5 Sound Player Not Working

Tags: android, html, audio

I Recorded Sound from android application and save this record on server, 
I listen this sound in web browser by HTML5 player by below code

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="http://mywebsite/uploads/attachment/2016/11/11/audio_1.wav" type="audio/wav">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

but when I show it on web browser player will be disabled and not working 
[Screen shot from disable player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BCiH.png)

Note: sound plays on mobile application properly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you supply the required MIME type for the browser you are using. `audio/ogg`, `audio/webm`, `audio/mp3` and `audio/wav` should cover all main browsers.

Comment: thank you, I'm using latest version of chrome browser and in other page in my website I got recorded from API and Worked fine 
and I'm using MIME in player here 
<source src="http://mywebsite/uploads/attachment/2016/11/11/audio_1.wav" type="audio/wav">
should I use in php ?

Comment: ```audio/wav``` should be fine for Chrome. Make sure your ```src``` attribute on the ```source``` element is a valid URL. I.e ```http://mywebsite.com...```

Comment: I added it like [link](http://mywebsite.com..) but still not working, also I add link directly in web browser also default player from chrome not working

Comment: Ok. Check your settings in Chrome. You may have denied access to the Audio features at some point.

Comment: I checked it and work fine with other audios (from another websites)

Comment: If you did at one time deny access to audio features, it would be per domain.